# Holding multiple items in a column on mysql

Tags: mysql

I am currently creating a database, it allows a user to upload a publication, which is stored in a table called paper, it stores the paper_id, title, abstract filename and topic_id .I have a table called topic which has topic_id and topic_name which i use for the user to select a topic for their publication. However i want the user to be able to select at least 3 topics, is this possible using this system? I have run out of ideas of how to do it and help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't store `topic_id` in the `paper` table.  Instead, create another normalized (many-to-many) table which links `topic_id` to `paper_id`.

```
/* Each paper can exist in this table as many times as necessary for all its topics */
CREATE TABLE paper_topics (
  paper_id INT NOT NULL,
  topic_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (paper_id) REFERENCES paper (paper_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (topic_id) REFERENCES topic (topic_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (paper_id, topic_id)
);
```

This will allow you to store as many topics per paper as necessary.

To retrieve the topics for a paper, use:

```
SELECT 
  paper.*,
  topic_name
FROM 
  paper
  LEFT JOIN paper_topics ON paper.paper_id = topic.paper_id
  LEFT JOIN topic ON topic.topic_id = paper_topic.topic_id
WHERE paper.paper_id = <some paper id value>
```

It is just about never a good idea to attempt to store multiple values in one column (such as a comma-separated list of `topic_id` in the `paper` table). The reason is that in order to query against it, you must use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) which drives up the complexity of performing joins and makes it impossible to utilize a column index when querying.

Comment: Thank you, how do i add the paper and its topic/topics in the paper_topics table?

Comment: @NickPocock `INSERT INTO paper_topics (paper_id, topic_id) VALUES (<the paperid>, <the topicid>)`

Comment: Is there any way to do this with php?

Comment: @NickPocock Like any other query in PHP. replace `<the paperid>`, etc, with a variable `$paperid` which points to the paper Id you want to insert. Same for topic.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, you can use serialization, like [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible (using a separate table each for papers and topics).  There would be a one to many relation between papers and topics.

http://www.databaseprimer.com/relationship_1tox.html