# MySQL - Is it wise?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm using MySQL as my main database for a simple "Social Network" I'm spending a few weeks on.

As with all social networks, the user requires a connection with their friends in order to make it social.

My theory was to either add another column onto my `user` database and name it connections. There, I would store a string of user id's separated by a comma, then split them when needed.

Another theory I had was to create a completely new table `connections` and use two columns "user_1" and "user_2". The database would then, when searching for friends, would perform a select looking for their id and so on.

The question is though: What would be the most efficient? If I'm to support large numbers of users, is it risky going with option 2?

Some advice would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: it's risky going with option one, not to mention more code and slower to parse the string every time you need to get the "connections"    Option 2 is the way to go.  That's how relational databases work.

Comment: Perhaps you should read about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalisation).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Holding multiple items in a column on mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947436/holding-multiple-items-in-a-column-on-mysql)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A normalized structure (option #2) is highly preferable for structuring the type of data that you describe. It will be far more efficient to query a narrow table with two integer columns than to split through an ever-growing list of IDs.

I would suggest reading about the different normalization forms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization (see "Normal Forms")

Comment: Also worth looking into table [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) and how they can make the connections table lightning fast.

Comment: well, it did seem the more obvious option but my knowledge of databases is rather small. Checking out the wikipedia page now too, thanks.

Comment: @AlexConnolly - good luck. With a normalized structure and some well-placed indexes, you can scale upwards for a long time (millions of records) without having to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

The second approach is much better. You're creating relations between the user by using a table 'connections'. This way you can create 'n:m' relations. If you want to add some kind of connection type ('love interest', 'friend') you can easily add it in a table, but not in a string.

There's another benefit: you don't have to think about the number of connections a user has. What would you use for the connections? A `varchar`? A `text`? Do you really want to parse this mess each and every time? How do you make sure that you don't add a connection twice?

tldr;: Use a table to show relations.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 will not end well. Go with a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

A separate table called `connections` without a doubt would be easier. having multiple values in one column defeats the purpose of a database, can you imagine searching for all friends of user1 with option 1?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can certainly deliver good performance with option 2. It's easier to select friends and to do calculations. There's a lot you can do with caching, multiple servers, load balancing and all that.

And realistically speaking: by the time you reach a large number of users, you'll be rewriting the system anyway to incorporate all the lessons you've learned along the way.